# Create List of file for a directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory of files for example:

```
\1.gif
\1.pdf
\1.doc
\2.gif
\2.pdf
\2.doc
\3.gif
\4.gif
```

How do I get a file with just the list of files (with extensions) that have unique filenames? (i.e. `3.gif`, `4.gif`)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i havent tested it, but try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd path\to\dir
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.gif') do (
   find "%%~ni" "%tmp%\u" >nul 2>&1 || echo %%~ni >> "%tmp%\u"
)
for /f %%i in ('type "%tmp%\u"') do (
   set inc=
   for /f %%j in ('dir %%i.gif /b') do set /a inc+=1
   if !inc! EQU 1 (dir /b %%i.* ^|find "log" /v >> log)
)
```

please feel free to comment if there are any mistakes, not in a position to test it right now.

Comment: nephi thanks WORKS GREAT.  a few quesitons
1) when i run the file i get "the system cannot find the path specified" and several "File Not Found".  Is there away to prevent this from being shown

Comment: 2) Is there a way to not include the "log" file in the log?
3) Is there a modification that would filter only specified file extension.  For example just a list of the unique file names that were *.gif?

Thanks again for you help/time.  Much appreciated.

Comment: yes to 2 and 3. see edit in a few min. as to number one, i get no errors, does it work other than that? is there any other info you can provide? ill work on it.

Comment: once more, couldn't test it.

Comment: did you replace the pushd path\to\dir with pushd and then the acctual path to the dir? do you have write privleges in the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as none of the file names contain the `=` character:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "eol== delims==" %%V in ('"set _ 2>nul"') do set "%%V="
for %%F in (*) do if not defined _%%~nF (set "_%%~nF=%%F") else set "_%%~nF=="
for /f "eol== tokens=2 delims==" %%F in ('"set _|findstr /v =="') do @echo %%F
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to restrict output to only one file type, .gif for example, then all you need is an extra FINDSTR:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "eol== delims==" %%V in ('"set _ 2>nul"') do set "%%V="
for %%F in (*) do if not defined _%%~nF (set "_%%~nF=%%F") else set "_%%~nF=="
for /f "eol== tokens=2 delims==" %%F in ('"set _|findstr /v ==|findstr /lie .gif"') do @echo %%F
```

Comment: I was able to get it to save to a log.txt.  Is there a way to filter only specific file extension in that file?  Thanks for your help/time.

Comment: i had an idea. i think that stack overflow should make it mandatory for a user to comment if they are going to down-vote, but have it be anonymous

Comment: @nephi12 - Those issues belong on meta, but I'm guessing that idea has already been discussed at length and won't fly.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with special characters like `!`, `=` and more.

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for %%a in (*) do set ".%%~na=%%~xa"& set /a $%%~na+=1
for /f "tokens=1*delims==." %%a in ('set .') do for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%c in ('set "$%%a"') do if %%c==1 echo(%%a.%%b
```